# Move coordinates from json to link (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have js code to get data from back endю

Here is code:

```
var speeddata = [];




 function getSpeedData() {
    var googleurl =
        "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=50.72389,3.32214|51.72389,3.32214&key=8IAceOk43NpWKpczMAzN5dVosUI=";
    $.getJSON(googleurl, function (data, status) {
        speedlimits = data;
        console.log(speedlimits);
    });
   var url = $('#getData').data('request-url');
   $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) {
            speeddata = data;
            console.log(speeddata);
        });
}
```

Here is what I get

[image]

I need to push those coordinates to url to this segment `path=50.72389,3.32214|51.72389,3.32214`

How I can do this, via js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var speeddata = [{Latitude2: 51.72389,Longitude2: 3.32214, Speed: 41},{Latitude2: 51.72389,Longitude2: 3.32214, Speed: 41}];
var args = 'yourpath = ';
for(var i=0; i < speeddata.length; i++){
      args += speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
      if(speeddata.length == (i+1)){
        break;
     }else{
        args += '|';
     }      
}
console.log(args);
```